# How to assert with chai that some div contains some text?

Tags: assert, chai

How to assert with chai that some div('.MyDive') contains text 'Some text'?

```
<div class="MyDive">
   <div>Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to pull in [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) to access elements on the DOM. Once you have that, you can assert against DOM elements using vanilla Chai like so:

```
expect($('div.MyDive').text()).to.have.string('Some text');
```

If you want to visually clean up your code a bit, you could also pull in a plugin like [`chai-jquery`](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery) and use a custom assertion, such as [`contain(text)`](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#containtext):

```
expect($('div.MyDive')).to.contain('Some text');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chai with WebdriverIO, you can do something like

```
expect = require('chai').expect;
client
    .element('.MyDive')
    .getText()
    .then(function (text) {
        expect(text).to.equal('Some text');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [`chai-dom`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-dom/) for this:

```js
import chai, { expect } from "chai";
import chaiDom from "chai-dom";

chai.use(chaiDom);

expect(document.querySelector(".MyDive")).to.have.text("Some text");
```

Comment: I noticed that `.to.not.have.text("some text")` does not work, is there any workaround for that?

Comment: How about `.not.to.have.text("some text")`?

Comment: simply doesn't work, if you try `.not.to.have.text("some text")` in "here we have some text" it pass